# Best place to add a Woocommerce single product page hook

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to add a section of boilerplate text about shipping info to the end of the WooCommerce single product page, right after the SKU and Categories. I would like to do this via hook if possible so I don't have to modify any WooCommerce code/template. The theme that I'm working with (Divi) has bunches of code already in functions.php, so I'd also like to avoid modifying that file, too.

My specific question is "what's the best place to add a WC hook for this purpose?" I know I could create a child theme and in its functions.php add a WC hook, but then I'd have the problem of calling in the original theme's functions.php (I don't know how to do that). Or is there a better way?

Comment: After considering the advice from @z-dimitry it dawned on me that somebody must have written this plugin already...and indeed someone has. I ended up choosing the free plugin "Booster for WooCommerce" at https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-jetpack/ and simply added my html to the "Product Custom Info Blocks" section using the "After product summary" position option on the single product form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create your own plugin

https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

Comment: Ah. The solution was in front of my face the whole time. Thank you.

Comment: It's my pleasure